# Syntax Error Jquery Rails (semicolon?)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here is my code that I'm including when I load the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
    $.get('/login', function(data){
        alert("test");
        $('#flash_content').html("hi");
        }, 'script');}

    function test2(){
    var jqxhr = $.get("/login", function(data) {
            $('#flash_content').html(data);}, 'script')
            .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
            .error(function(request, status,error) { alert(error); })
            .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });}

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from following its href
    test2();
    });});
    </script>
```

When I call test2(), I can see in my rails server log that it renders the views that it should, and in firebug I see my response from the ajax get is indeed the form I want to overwrite onto the page, however nothing on the page actually changes.  I've replaced "Data" with the string "hi" and that indeed gets put into the page.  As you can see, an alert pops up and tells me :

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

Here is my controller method for signing in:

```
@user = User.new
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { }
    format.js  {render :layout => false }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  end
```

and the view that should be rendered:

```
    <%= form_tag user_sessions_path, :method => :post do  %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :username %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %><br />
    <%= password_field_tag :password %></br>
    Remember me : <%= check_box_tag :remember %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I've been at this for hours, so maybe I'm not seeing something obvious :(  Thanks.

Comment: I found where the error seems to be coming from.  When rails creates the form :
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/user_sessions" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="eLD3Gve1elFv63exY8MRnULKOuOBmefn47STC5J8Xr8=" /></div>

The error above is in reference to line 4 of the form i.e. this. but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling jquery that what's being returned is javascript (last parameter to `$.get`). This tells jquery that when it gets your response it should evaluate it.

However your response is html - trying to evaluate that as javascript doesn't make sense. You should either be omitting that parameter (letting jquery guess) or set it to 'html'.

Rails will still use the `format.js` block for an xhr request, although I believe you'll need to put it before the `format.html` version.

Comment: I've been looking around and I see what you mean.  How would I use a completely jquery/AJAX approach?  by creating a new.js.erb and putting my replace function in there?   And if I were to use an html response, how would I specify a specific view, without the layout.  The problem is, if javascript is disabled and I have (render layout => false), then my site will be nothing but a webform for that specific view.

Comment: I actually just changed it, and I have whatever is in my 'new.js.erb' running on the page when it gets returned, though it gets run twice.  In the console, it shows my jquery.js being run twice.  I have normal rails settings on, nothing extra in terms of javascript includes. It shows the following  files as being included on the page: jquery.js, jquery_ujs.js, application.js, and rails.js.

Comment: after fooling around in the application.js, this double calling doesn't happen if i remove "jquery.js".  But then no js works anywhere.  The others dont make a difference it seems for this.

Comment: You don't need jquery_ujs.js and rails.js